# skipDefaultCheckout true option is skipping all the stages and going to postActions stage

Tags: go, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I need to check out the code into $GOPATH/src/dev-DIR folder. but due to  **skipDefaultCheckout true** option checkout scm and other stages are not executing. Directly post actions are getting executing Please help me where am I going wrong?

````
pipeline {
 agent {node {label 'project_a'}}
    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true 
    }
     environment {
        PATH = "$PATH:/opt/jenkins/:/usr/local/go/bin/"
        GIT_REPO = get_gitrepo()
        GOPATH= "${env.WORKSPACE}"
        PROJECT_WORKSPACE = "${env.WORKSPACE}/src/dev-DIR"
    }
      stages {
        stage('checkout scm'){
            steps{
                dir ("${GOPATH}/src/dev-DIR"){
                    checkout scm
                }
            }
        }
         stage('Install Prerequisites') {
           // go get -t
        }
}
     post{
        //some actions
    }
}
    ```
````